# Canvas flickers when trying to draw image with updated src

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

get image of canvas whenever there is change in canvas

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

socket.emit('updateCanvasImage', canvas.toDataURL());
```

draw image on new canvas somewhere else

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvasImg');

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var image = new Image();

image.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(this, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
};

socket.on('updateCanvasImage', function (img) {
    image.src = img;
});
```

The canvas flickers when socket changes the `image.src`

There are lots of questions like these here, but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: That's very unclear. Do you draw this image only here? Or are you continuously drawing it in an animation loop?

Comment: whenever I drag an object from source canvas, I am drawing destination canvas `onDrag`, so yes I am continuously drawing the destination canvas whenever anything moves in the source canvas.

Comment: In that case, it's normal: whenever you change the `src` of your image, its content will be cleared, and when the canvas tries to render it, it can't, which will produce frames without any image, until the newly set media is loaded and parsed. Without seeing your code it's quite hard to offer you a correct solution, but basically it could be: *let current = the currently loaded image, accessible to drag-event. on(socket.updateCanvasImage, let newImage = a new Image on which you set the new src). on(newImage.load, current = new Image)* with this simple structure, you will avoid the flickers.

Answer (score 4):

#### Do not use events to render content

Do not use events to redraw the canvas. Image content is presented to the display at a fixed rate, while most events are not synced to the display rate, the mismatch between display rate and event rates can cause flicker.

#### `requestAnimationFrame`

When you repeatedly update any visual content, be that the canvas or other DOM content, you should use `requestAnimationFrame` to call a render function. This function should then render all the content ready for the next display frame.

When the render function returns the changes will be held in a backbuffer until the display hardware is ready to display the next frame.

#### Removing flicker

Thus to fix your problem create a render function that is tied to the display rate.

```
var image = new Image();    
var update = true; // if true redraw
function renderFunction(){
    if(update){  // only raw if needed
       update = false;
       context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    }
    requestAnimationFrame(renderFunction);
}
requestAnimationFrame(renderFunction);
```

Then in the events just get the new image state and flag update when ready to draw

```
image.onload = () => update = true;    
socket.on('updateCanvasImage', src => {update = false; image.src = src});
```

Do the same with the drag events

This will ensure you never have any flicker, and also you can check to see if the image updates are arriving faster than can be delayed and thus throttle back the image update rate.

#### Double buffering the canvas

There are many times where the canvas content is updated from one or more different sources, from a video, camera, a draw command (from mouse, touch, code), or from a stream of images.

In these cases it is best to use a second canvas that you keep offscreen (in RAM) and use as the source for display. This makes the display canvas just a view, that is independent of the content.

To create a second canvas;

```
function createCanvas(width, height){
    const myOffScreenCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    myOffScreenCanvas.width = width;
    myOffScreenCanvas.height = height;
    // attach the context to the canvas for easy access and to reduce complexity.
    myOffScreenCanvas.ctx = myOffScreenCanvas.getContext("2d"); 
    return myOffScreenCanvas;
 }
```

Then in the render function you can display it

```
var background = createCanvas(1024,1024); 
var scale = 1; // the current scale 
var origin = {x : 0, y : 0}; // the current origin
function renderFunction(){
    // set default transform
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);

    // clear
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    // set the current view
    ctx.setTransform(scale,0,0,scale,origin.x,origin.y);

    // draw the offscreen canvas
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0);

    requestAnimationFrame(renderFunction);
}
requestAnimationFrame(renderFunction);
```

Thus your image load draws to the offscreen canvas

```
image.onload = () => background.ctx.drawImage(0, 0, background.width, background.height);    
socket.on('updateCanvasImage', src => image.src = src);
```

And your mouse drag events need only update the canvas view. The render function will render the next frame using the updated view. You can also add zoom and rotation.

```
const mouse  = {x : 0, y : 0, oldX : 0, oldY : 0, button : false}
function mouseEvents(e){
    mouse.oldX = mouse.x;
    mouse.oldY = mouse.y;
    mouse.x = e.pageX;
    mouse.y = e.pageY;
    mouse.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.button;
    if(mouse.button){
        origin.x += mouse.x - mouse.oldX;
        origin.y += mouse.y - mouse.oldY;
    }
}
["down","up","move"].forEach(name => document.addEventListener("mouse" + name, mouseEvents));
```

Comment: ... it is implementation independent, but on chrome, when you use only one `image`, you will still have flickers in between of the src setting and the loading of the media: https://jsfiddle.net/vxuy4nmc/
Firefox doesn't behave like that though...

Comment: @Kaiido I have fixed the bug.

Comment: not really, you fixed it in the case of an animation loop that would only render this image, which is a quite rare scenario. E.g in OP's case, dragging, you won't do `alert('please stop dragging'); image.src = src`

Comment: @Kaiido The OP has not shown how he drags, he may well be dragging the canvas or content derived from the canvas. Recreating a new image for every few frames or more will incur a lot of GC hits and should be avoided.

Comment: GC will kick anyway: socket is transmitting new data which needs to be cleaned, but yeah, no need for a new Image every time... You can use only two.

Comment: @Blindman67 Its still flickering, I am dragging the object inside the source canvas, on which, whole source canvas image is sent for rendering on new canvas, basically what I am trying to achieve is screen sharing sort of functionality.

Comment: You can double buffer the image by creating a second canvas offscreen, you use that canvas as the display image in the render function `ctx.drawImage(myOffScreenCanvas,drag.x,drag.y)` and when you get content from a socket render it to the offscreen canvas on the onload event. I will update the answer to show you.

Comment: @Kaiido Not an image but a canvas if you want to double buffer the content. One canvas for display and the second offscreen for content.

Comment: @BhushanBabar i have updated the answer using a offscreen canvas and shown how you can drag using a view.

Comment: For an non modified image that won't change anything to use a canvas or an img. (Well yes, if ypu use the canvas, you'll be holding twice the image's data in memory...) ps:same goes with video btw (what a strange idea to pass through a canvas in this case...)

Comment: @Kaiido An image from a dataURL requires memory for the pixels, and memory for the dataURL as a string (with 3 out of every 8bits used to store data). I know of no way to remove that bloat from the image. Using a canvas removes the dataURL making for a smaller memory footprint. It also allows for other benefits that aid to reduce memory, CPU, and bandwidth loads. (eg sending part of image/canvas, sending render commands rather than pixels, Having content,  overlays / text / what not, rendered once, not every frame) In my view it is the image that is strange.

Comment: I said strange about the video, since you'd have to render every frame on the offscreen to then redraw the offscreen on the rendering one. Also, you can remove the dataURI bloat by loading the image through a blobURI instead of loading it through dataURI. And your solution still keeps the `image` (and its src)  in memory...

Comment: @Kaiido  The video would just a be part of the whole. If the goal was to create a draggable updating image and that was all why use the canvas at all. There is likely a reason the canvas is being used and that would be associated with some form of image manipulation.I would not send images i would send render calls, state , and associated media URLs

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you change the src of an HTMLImageElement, its content is cleared, and when the canvas tries to render it, it can't.

Because of this, you will experience frames without any image (*flickers*), until the newly set media is loaded and parsed [(fiddle reproducing the issue)](https://jsfiddle.net/vxuy4nmc/).

Without seeing your code it's quite hard to offer you a correct solution, but a simple structure could be:

- let current = the currently loaded image, accessible to animation-loop/drag-event.
- on( socket.updateCanvasImage, let newImage = a new Image on which you set the new src).
- on( newImage.load, current = new Image ).

With this simple structure, you will avoid the flickers.

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function animLoop(time){ // draws continously
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(current, 0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillText(time, 20,20);
  requestAnimationFrame(animLoop);
  }
var current = new Image();

function loadImage(){
  var img = new Image(); // if you really want to optimize your code for memory impact, you could declare it only once out of the function...
  img.onload = function(){
    current = this; // update the image to be rendered with the new & loaded one
    setTimeout(loadImage, 2000); // start loading a new one in 2 sec (will be rendered even later)
    }
  img.onerror = loadImage;
  img.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons' + urls[++url_index % urls.length]+'?'+Math.random();
  }

var url_index = 0;
var urls = [
  //Martin Falbisoner [CC BY-SA 4.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0)], via Wikimedia Commons
 '/2/2d/Okayama_Castle%2C_November_2016_-02.jpg',
 //Diego Delso [CC BY-SA 4.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0)], via Wikimedia Commons
 '/9/9b/Gran_Mezquita_de_Isfah%C3%A1n%2C_Isfah%C3%A1n%2C_Ir%C3%A1n%2C_2016-09-20%2C_DD_34-36_HDR.jpg',
 //Dietmar Rabich / Wikimedia Commons / “Münster, LVM, Skulptur -Körper und Seele- -- 2016 -- 5920-6” / CC BY-SA 4.0, via Wikimedia Commons
 '/5/53/M%C3%BCnster%2C_LVM%2C_Skulptur_-K%C3%B6rper_und_Seele-_--_2016_--_5920-6.jpg',
 //By Charlesjsharp (Own work, from Sharp Photography, sharpphotography) [CC BY-SA 4.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0)], via Wikimedia Commons
 '/4/4b/Campo_flicker_(Colaptes_campestris)_female.JPG'
 ];
loadImage();
animLoop();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

---

**Edit:**
**This is only true for chrome**, Firefox doesn't behave like that and actually only starts the parsing of the image when we call `drawImage`. This will hold the canvas' drawing during this time. If this is a problem, you can try to lower this with an ImageBitmap Object, but with the big images I used in demo, this halt is still there...

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function animLoop(time){ // draws continously
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(current, 0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillText(time, 20,20);
  requestAnimationFrame(animLoop);
  }
var current = new Image();

function loadImage(){
  var img = new Image();
  img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  img.onload = function(){
    createImageBitmap(this, 0,0,this.width, this.height).then(function(bmp){
      current = bmp; // update the image to be rendered with an ImageBitmap
      }).catch(e=>console.log(e))
    setTimeout(loadImage, 2000); // start loading a new one in 2 sec (will be rendered even later)
    }
  img.onerror = loadImage;
  img.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons' + urls[++url_index % urls.length]+'?'+Math.random();
  }

var url_index = 0;
var urls = [
  //Martin Falbisoner [CC BY-SA 4.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0)], via Wikimedia Commons
 '/2/2d/Okayama_Castle%2C_November_2016_-02.jpg',
 //Diego Delso [CC BY-SA 4.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0)], via Wikimedia Commons
 '/9/9b/Gran_Mezquita_de_Isfah%C3%A1n%2C_Isfah%C3%A1n%2C_Ir%C3%A1n%2C_2016-09-20%2C_DD_34-36_HDR.jpg',
 //Dietmar Rabich / Wikimedia Commons / “Münster, LVM, Skulptur -Körper und Seele- -- 2016 -- 5920-6” / CC BY-SA 4.0, via Wikimedia Commons
 '/5/53/M%C3%BCnster%2C_LVM%2C_Skulptur_-K%C3%B6rper_und_Seele-_--_2016_--_5920-6.jpg',
 //By Charlesjsharp (Own work, from Sharp Photography, sharpphotography) [CC BY-SA 4.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0)], via Wikimedia Commons
 '/4/4b/Campo_flicker_(Colaptes_campestris)_female.JPG'
 ];
loadImage();
animLoop();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

**Re-Edit:**
Since what you do is screen sharing you might also want to consider [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/) along with [`canvas.captureStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/captureStream) instead of sending still images.